# Find directory structure in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my CodeIgniter code to find the directory structure of a folder in my own server, but it is only going one level deep. I want to list all the subdirectories in the given `$path`. What is the error in this code?

```
function finddir($path)
{
    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $dir=directory_map($path,1);
    //echo"$path";
    foreach ($dir as $key => $subdir) 
    {
        //echo $subdir."<br/>";
        if(is_dir($subdir))
        {
            echo "<h3>$subdir</h3>";
            $this->finddir($subdir);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "$subdir<br>";
        }

    }
}
```

The output goes only one level deep. Since I'm using recursion, I want it to go into deeper levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes more sense to make two functions so that you're not regenerating the array within a recursive function. This way it's generated once, and you are recursively getting values from just that one array. Unless the directory class is broken, you shouldn't need to check if it's a directory. If it's an array, it's a directory:

```
function finddir($path){
    $this->load->helper('directory');
    $dir=directory_map($path);
    $this->recursive($dir);
}

function recursive($arr) {
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)){
            echo "<h3>$key</h3>";
            echo "<ul>\n";
            $this->recursive($val);
            echo "</ul>\n";
        } else {
            echo "<li>".$val."</li>\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Your break tags `<br/>` don't show the structure well, so I changed it to use nested lists.

I just noticed that you are pasing a value of 1 to the `directory_map()` function. That limits it to just one level, so you probably want to leave that out if you want to goes all the way with the recursion:

```
$dir=directory_map($path);
```

Comment: thanxx ..... it is a better option but it loses the optimization of code, nyways it solves my problem .... THnxxx Again

Answer (score 1):

Try the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) for this

```
function finddir($path)
{
    $objects = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    foreach($objects as $name => $object){
        echo "$name\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doint it this way?

The [directory_map('source directory')](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html) returns you an array with sub-arrays (and sub-sub-arrays if applicable based on path).

You get the complete tree - just loop over array and print/use as needed, Use [is_array($subdir)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) to test if its directory or file leaf.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$dir=directory_map($path,1)` remove number 1 so it displays this way `$dir=directory_map($path)` since that number will only return the first level directory only.